# An WPF application to create installer

Tags: wpf, installation

I want to create an Desktop application using WPF, which will be able to create an setup of provided binaries. How can i achieve this?

For example,

Application should accept list of binaries like zyz.exe,xyc.dll or whatever, application should generate the setup file.

Comment: For simple installer: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects, For more advanced: http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Thank you i will check it out.

Comment: You should also remove your question before it gets downvotes and marked as duplicate